# Installer compilation errors (strstr function related and otherwise)

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I couldn't find this in any searches and have been fighting with these scripts this past week, trying to learn how NSIS' scripting works from scratch in the process. Cutting to the chase, here's what I'm encountering and take note I'm working with another person's scripts in the process:

Initial state of the scripts:
Fails to enable the program's functionality (which is to present an easy to use .exe to call in the command line that may then be followed by other commands in relation to another file to extract its contents).
Presents warnings that AddEnvVar and un.RemoveFromEnvVar functions are not called.

Add calls to the functions in the .nsi file in the appropriate sections.

Installer compiles, but when run presents an Installer Corrupted: Invalid Opcode error.

Okay...Not sure why that's happening. There's another script called EnvVarUpdate present, maybe that's it. Add a line in the .nsi to include it. Then I run into this:

> Error: Function named "StrStr" already exists. Error in macro
>   STRFUNC_FUNC on macroline 16 Error in macro FUNCTION_STRING_StrStr on
>   macroline 1 Error in macro _IncludeStrFunction on macroline 2
>   !include: error in script: "EnvVarUpdate.nsh" on line 50

Okay. Try commenting out those lines to get it through...And I hit this:

> !insertmacro: macro "FUNCTION_STRING_StrStr" requires 0 parameter(s),
>   passed 3! Error in macro EnvVarUpdate on macroline 84

I have no idea if EnvVarUpdate needs to be included to begin with (since it wasn't originally included in the .nsi script I'm at a loss for what it's even doing there) and I can't figure out why the calls to AddEnvVar and un.RemoveFromEnvVar are corrupting the installer. It seemed logical to me that for since these files were published with the intent being easy compilation that all the files would be necessary, but with the function calls missing and the exclusion of one of the scripts in the .nsi file rendering the compiled installer dysfunctional, I'm led to believe he may have made some mistakes in the process.

My guess is since he also published a compiled installer that works hosted on his own site, he incidentally left the open files a little broken as he figured out the right way to do it. However, personally, I'd still like to repair them if I can figure out how to enable others to manually compile the installers if they like.

If it might help, here's a [link](https://github.com/bwesterb/ftldat/tree/master/win-installer) to the fellow's code on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

AddToPath.nsh contains two functions that manipulate %path% (AddToPath and un.RemoveFromPath) and two generic functions that can manipulate any environment variable (AddToEnvVar and un.RemoveFromEnvVar) but those two functions are never used so you get a warning.

To remove the warnings you can just comment out those two unused functions.

EnvVarUpdate.nsh uses the StrStr that is a part of NSIS so you get a problem because it is already defined in AddToPath.nsh

A common pattern for utility functions like these is to put the function inside a macro and then allow the .nsi to select the functions it uses by inserting the macro (And the macro creates the function at that point):

```
!macro Foo un
Function ${un}Foo
MessageBox mb_ok "Hello from Foo"
FunctionEnd
!macroend

...

!insertmacro Foo "" ; Use function Foo in installer?
#!insertmacro Foo "un." ; Use function Foo in uninstaller?

Section
call Foo
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Hm...I had gathered something of that. Did the commenting out, but as noted, it seems to not enable the program to do what it should. Would that be associated with the reboot flags being set to true? Or simply how programs modifying %path% tend to work? Because I tested rebooting my system to see if it would enable the program but nothing came of it.  Also, when you suggest inserting the macros, am I understanding properly in that you mean writing those lines to the .nsi file?

Comment: I don't know what the program should or should not do so I cannot really hep with that. Run cmd.exe and type path or echo %path%. The !insertmacro call goes in the .nsi but the !macro around the function has to be in the .nsh

Comment: Finally got back to revisiting this. I'm still at a loss, but I think I may have a better question to focus on: Why would adding calls to functions that are established in the AddToPath file (e.g. AddToEnvVar/un.RemoveFromEnvVar) corrupt the installer? I'm assuming that the the whole EnvVarUpdate may be included only to substantiate those functions' operations, but without being called in the .nsi...It again seems incredibly confusing.

I think I need to put some more time in trying to get more literate with these NSIS scripts...

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head which instructions can generate the invalid opcode error, most likely a pop without a push... (The dumpstate plugin is useful if you want to inspect the stack)

Comment: I went over this again, and as far as I can tell regarding the AddToPath file he's using, it's completely unmodified from his [source](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Path_Manipulation#The_Functions). When using a header file, if you're to make use of its functions, they must be called in the appropriate sections in the script file, right? Except that creates errors in this case. ~_~ I'm pretty positive the same goes for the EnvVarUpdate file he's included as well (that is, its being a copy too), so I'm completely lost as to what's going on with all this. Thanks for your patience and responses!

Comment: !include just "inserts" the text into the .nsi. No matter what I do I cannot get the bad opcode problem: http://pastebin.com/YhSKrAsW and http://pastebin.com/Psu4zqPv

Comment: I figured it out. I was unintentionally being somewhat dense this whole time. It was nothing in the code itself, but in a part preceding the installer compilation. Part of the process involved running PyInstaller with a spec file, which generates a build and dist folder. For some reason, it was making one more dist folder than necessary, so when it compiled and I tried using the program, it couldn't find it because the program was one subfolder deeper than the setup ever expected. Man, I feel really stupid right now. Thanks again, and sorry to have taken your time. (I hope not too much!)